# not receiving push notification enterprise app

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I have made an app which is on enterprise account, its for several employees, the .pem certificate has been uploaded to the server, but still I'm not receiving any push notification, knowing that the added all the functions and the delegate, but nothing received. the app is asking the user if he wants to receive push notification, and we are pressing on "allow", the token is been sent to the server, the didRegisterForRemoteNotifications is been called , sandbox is set to 1 (development), but nothing received

```
@interface AppDelegate ()<CLLocationManagerDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
.
.
.
+ (void)registerPushNotifications {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
.
.
.
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Right now, this can not be answered. Is `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` ever called? Did the user accept Push Notifications? Has the app been signed with a Provisioning Profile that includes the Push Capability? Are you using the correct Push Environment (Sandbox, Production)?

Comment: edited, done , please check it

Comment: I'm using sandbox,